# Only show link if the page is a child of a child in WordPress

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

Hay guys, i have a general navigation which looks like this:

```
PAGE 1
    PAGE 1.1
        PAGE 1.1.1
        PAGE 1.1.2
    PAGE 1.2
        PAGE 1.2.1
```

I want to display a link on pages 1.1.1, 1.1.2 and 1.2.1. As you can see these are childrens' children of the main navigation.

How would i do this in WordPress?

Comment: I don't believe it's possible using `wp_list_pages()`, you'd have to write a custom function or query for it.

Comment: I don't want to use wp_list_pages(), as i don't need to list the pages, I just want it so that a link only appears on the grandchild pages. I know i need to use $post->post_parent with something else to get it working, but i can't think what.

Comment: @diEcho: That's going to be a huge waste on server resources.

Comment: You don't really need to use jQuery for this! All i want to do is display a link on my page if the post is a grandchild to a top level page!

Comment: Try asking this on http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Comment: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_ancestors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use following code snippet inside [the loop](http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop) to achieve this objective:

```
<?php
if ($post->post_parent) {
   $parent = get_page($post->post_parent);
   $parentLink = get_permalink($parent->ID);

   if ($parent->post_parent) {
      $grandParent = get_page($parent->post_parent);
      $grandParentLink = get_permalink($grandParent->ID);
   }
}

// display the links to parent and grand parent pages now
echo $parentLink . ' | ' . $grandParentLink;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

how about just using:

```
<?php if( is_page('PAGENAME') ) { ?>
   <a href="#">Your Link</a>
<?php } ?>
```

then the link will only be shown on that page...if you want it on a few different pages then:

```
<?php if( is_page('PAGENAME') || 
          is_page('OTHERPAGE') || 
          is_page('ANOTHERPAGE') 
        ) { ?>
   <a href="#">Your Link</a>
<?php } ?>
```

this normaly works ok for me for what i need it to do..